# Maintenance complexity of code in .net

Tags: c#, .net, metrics

Trying to figure out the complexities of developed code,i found the ,
**Cyclomatic complexity**(software metric (measurement), used to indicate the complexity of a program. It is a quantitative measure of the number of linearly independent paths through a program's source code.) and **Maintenance complexity**(It shows how complex is your code to maintain) as below screen shots from project in visual studio - `c#` :

Cyclomatic :

[image]

Maintenance :

[image]

Further research showed me parameters which determine the complexities like below (maintenance complexity parameter)

[image]

My question is how these numbers are assigned for the parameters ?

Comment: Why did you tagged `C#` and `.net` in this.

Comment: screen shots from project in visual studio - c#

Comment: It looks at the IL in the assembly, decompiling it back to the original C# keyword.  Not unlike the way Reflector or ILSpy work.  It is just an estimate, it notoriously falters on code that is not easy to decompile.  Like code that uses Linq or *dynamic*, it goes into the red zone far too quickly.

Comment: ohh..so it depends on IL ?

Comment: My guess is that the numbers were chosen more or less randomly. Measuring 'complexity' is very hard (especially if complexity is not further defined). You may find this post helpful: https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/mccabe-cyclomatic-complexity/.

Comment: Maintenance complexity is described here: http://www.skorkin.com/2010/11/code-metrics-heres-your-new-code-metric/ DevExpress basically chose arbitrary values with the goal of a higher number meaning "harder to maintain" according to their experience and guidelines.